# Obter largura em pixeis

Tags: javascript, svg

Quero obter o valor em pixels de um elemento svg que esta definido em %. Tenho o seguinte exemplo, mas devolve m o valor 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/n6vo8ksr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O segredo é o [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Ele retorna a informação desejada há algum tempo. Funciona em todos os navegadores que não são muito antigos.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += document.getElementById('rect').getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

```html
<svg width=100% height=100%>
    <rect id=rect rx=0 ry=0 x=0 y=0 width=100% height=50px fill=HoneyDew />
</svg>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/GetPixelsSVG.js).

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar o [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) que retorna um objecto com as dimensões do elemento.

Neste teu exemplo seria:

```
{
    height: 50,
    width: 813,
    left: 8,
    bottom: 58,
    right: 821,
    top: 8
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('rect');
var width_plan = el.getBoundingClientRect().width
alert(width_plan);  // 821
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hxen50jq/